# rand function does not run in my if statement

Tags: laravel

On my practice project i want to create instances to check when a user is loading a voucher before his account is recharged..

Here is my controller

```
Public function postVoucher(){

$posted = Input::get();


$vouchers = $posted[voucher_code];


$balance ='10';


if($vouchers == rand(100000,999999)){

 $user = Auth::user();

 $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

 $user_credit = Auth::user()->credit;

 $load_balance = $user_credit + $balance;

 Auth::user()->credit =  $load_balance;

 $user->save();

 $voucher = new Voucher;

 $voucher->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

 $voucher->voucher_code = $posted['voucher_code'];

 $voucher->credit = $balance;

 $voucher->save();

return 'your balance has been loaded;

 }else{
return 'invalid voucher';
  }
```

}

PROBLEM

My problem am having with this code is am able to recharge the user  balance but the if statement does not run when posting the voucher so any number entered recharge the balance with 10.

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE

1.i want to be able to only recharge the user balance with 10 only  if the voucher entered meets the  if statement
  if($vouchers == rand (100000,999999))

IDEA

i wil be generating randomly numbers which will be used as the vouchers by the rand function and because the each voucher carries different balance .i wanted to use the rand function and define the ranges for each value eg.

For 10
rand(1000,1900);
For 20
rand(2000,2900);e.t.c

So then when I send the user the user these generated numbers in recharging their voucher the post voucher controller checks the voucher against the rand function in my if statement in my controller before credit is loaded.

Is it possible to do that

HOw do i do that ?

Any example to showcase wil be happy

Comment: With your code as it is now, there is a 1:~900000 chance that your `if` statement will run.

Comment: How do I go about it

Comment: I don't know, what are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to match certain voucher numbers, and if a member enters them, give them 10 credits?

Comment: Yes that's the main idea I want implement

Comment: Using the random function to check the values is not what you need to do. You need to use rand to generate them before hand and store them (most likely in a database). Then you can compare the user's voucher to the ones you've already generated.